# Qual è il significato di "parentesi" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Per festeggiare il nuovo lavoro di Moe, andarono a Cherry Street, dove battevano le puttane piú economiche. Decisero di prenderne una insieme. Ma Diamante non ne trovò neanche una che gli piacesse – gli sembravano tutte volgari, logore e repellenti – e Moe raccolse la piú brutta della strada. Le mancavano tre denti e aveva due **parentesi** vizze attorno alla bocca.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "parentesi" nel testo sopra citato? Ho cercato questo termine in alcuni dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso nel contesto di questo passaggio.

Comment: Penso si riferisca a due segni grinzosi (vizze) a forma di parentesi che aveva intorno alla bocca

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le parentesi sono un segno di interpunzione, oltreché un simbolo che si usa in aritmetica e algebra. Sono di tre tipi: tonde (), quadre [], graffe {}. Per capire il significato in questo contesto, dobbiamo pensare alla forma delle parentesi tonde e immaginare che siano così le due linee/rughe che segnano i lati della bocca, più o meno marcatamente. In questo caso, il segno è marcato (le parentesi sono *vizze*, vale a dire “appassite, grinzose”).

Comment: Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI12/GDLI_12_ocr_598.pdf) appare l'accezione "fedina, basettone", ma quello che spieghi tu mi pare che abbia più senso.

Comment: Se ne parla anche su questo [sito web](https://www.giancarlodellisanti.com/correzioni-solchi-naso-genieni-roma.html):
«I solchi naso-labiali, o naso genieni, sono le profonde rughe che corrono dal lato del naso all'angolo della bocca. Queste rughe anche dette “le parentesi” si sviluppano con l'età e possono essere uno dei primi segni visibili dell'invecchiamento del viso, specie nell’uomo.»

Comment: Che bello poter leggere di nuovo una tua risposta, @Benedetta!

Comment: Grazie, anche delle tue aggiunte, @Charo!